# How to define custom config for a mysql docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've read multiple examples about this, yet I cannot overcome this issue.
I have services defined in my `docker-compose.yml`. I'd like to add a volume to the db (mysql) service so I can define custom configurations.

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:
 # local db
  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
          - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootpassword
          MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
          MYSQL_USER: myuser
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
```

The file structure looks like this, I think the relative path is fine:

```
app/
├─ docker/
│  ├─ mysql/
│  │  ├─ my.cnf
├─ docker-compose.yml
```

This is the contents of `./docker/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=""
sql_mode=""
```

After setting up my containers, in the db container I run: `SELECT @@sql_mode;`, and I see the default config, not the overridden one from the `custom.cnf`. When I try to read the contents of `/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf`, I get `cat: custom.cnf: Is a directory`

What am I doing wrong, could you help with this please?
(Extra info: I'm newbie to Docker.)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom configuration file in env_file variable under your particular service.

```
services:
 # local db
  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
          - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootpassword
          MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
          MYSQL_USER: myuser
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
      env_file: 
          - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
```

Comment: moving line `- ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf` to `volumes` property instead of `env_file` make it work